# gcc Linkage option -L: Alternative ways how to specify the path to the dynamic library

Tags: c, gcc, dynamic, linker

If I compile my source code with "-L." the dynamic library libmd5.so can be found.

```
gcc main.c -g -O2 -Wall -o main -L. -lmd5 -lcr
```

But if I leave the "-L."-option away, the linker does not find the dynamic library. How can I change that without having to invoke "-L."?

(additional info libmd5.so and libmd5.so.1.0.1 are located in /home/user/ba)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's really nothing wrong with the -L flag, so you shouldn't try so hard to get rid of it - is it at runtime you have problems, as the system won't load the libraries you link to ?  Here's some options :

- Add /home/user/ba to /etc/ld.so.conf (or similar for your OS) and run ldconfig afterwards. This will be system wide.
- Set the LIBRARY_PATH(for link time) and LD_LIBRARY_PATH(for run time) environment variable. `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/user/ba` and `export LIBRARY_PATH=/home/user/ba` .This will have effect only for the current shell.
- Set the rpath in the executable (you still need the `-L .` here though). Add `-L /home/user/ba -Wl,-rpath,/home/user/ba` to your linker flags. This will have effect only for the executable you're making.
- Place your shared libraries in a system wide library search path such as `/usr/lib`. This will be system wide.

The above have effect at runtime as well - it'll try to find libmd5.so in /home/user/ba or other library search paths for the system when you run the app as well.

Comment: Thank you. I did not really wanted to get rid of it. But I did not know how to change automake so that the "-L." is included when I compile my project with Anjuta.

Comment: Beware that `LIBRARY_PATH` is tried *after* the standard search path (e.g. /usr/lib64). So it cannot be used to override the standard library search path. On the other hand, `-L` is tried *before* the standard search path.

Answer (score 1):

you can set the `LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable.

```
export LIBRARY_PATH=/home/user/ba
```